# Alternative of System.Web.HttpContext.Current when using ProgressBox

Tags: sitecore

Im running a long process using ProgressBox, and in that process im using System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath() method, which throws exception because System.Web.HttpContext.Current is null, Is there any method to do same functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
HostingEnvironment.MapPath(string path)
```

Comment: Ahmed, you specifically asked for a solution that existed within the Sitecore API.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

```
Sitecore.IO.FileUtil.MapPath(string path)
```

Maps a virtual file path to a physical file path.

**Parameters**
path - A virtual file path.

**Return Value**
The physical file path.

**Remarks**
If the file path is blank, contains a backslash () or contains the string "://" the path itself is returned.

**Example**
The following example returns the physical filename of the mydata.xml file in the data folder. Afterwards the filename variable holds a value like "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\default website\sitecore\data\mydata.xml".

```
string filename = FileUtil.MapPath("/sitecore/data/mydata.xml");
```